# Check if inputed date is under 18

Tags: python, date

How can I check with a inputed date if that date of birthday is under 18?

```
year=int(input("Year born: "))
month = int(input("Month born: "))
day = int(input("Day born: "))
date = date(year,month,day)
```

What code can I use with `date.today()` in order to check if user is under 18? Because if I substract 2022- year it could be under 17 because he was born in December

**UPDATE:**

```
def is_under_18(birth):
year=int(input("Year born: "))
month = int(input("Month born: "))
day = int(input("Day born: "))
date = date(year,month,day)
now = date.today()
return (
    now.year - birth.year < 18
    or now.year - birth.year == 18 and (
        now.month < birth.month 
        or now.month == birth.month and now.day <= birth.day
    )
)
```

Should it be like this? I didn't understand. And I would also like to add an `if` he is older than 18, then `print("You are over 18")`

Comment: Convert the input to a `date` using the `date.date()` function. Then subtract that date from `date.today()` to get the difference. Then check if that difference is less than 18 years.

Comment: @Barmar And how do you define "18 years" in days as comparison target? It depends on many factors, at least - leap years (and you should add one day, if current year is a leap year and current date is after 28th Dec...). Given that 18 years is an child/adult border in many countries, even 1 day me be a problem and cause penalties by law.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare all date parts sequentially:

```py
from datetime import date

def is_under_18(birth):
    now = date.today()
    return (
        now.year - birth.year < 18
        or now.year - birth.year == 18 and (
            now.month < birth.month 
            or now.month == birth.month and now.day <= birth.day
        )
    )
```

In most countries people are considered to have age of `n+1` at the next day after their birthday, so the last comparison uses `<=`.

You may also consider `dateutil` library that provides `relativedelta` class that gives you better difference approach (full years + full months + full days + ...).

The function above accepts one argument (`birth`), which should be a date inputted by your user.

```py
year = int(input("Year born: "))
month = int(input("Month born: "))
day = int(input("Day born: "))
# Please, STOP using `date` as variable name here!
birth = date(year,month,day)

if is_under_18(birth):
    print('Under 18')
else:
    print('Adult')
```

Comment: I could not get it right :)

Comment: I just updated the question if you could check :)

Comment: I added a usage example to the answer.

Comment: now it worked, the only thing is say I add a user which his birthday is the 25th of November 2004. The program lets me add it because it does not count the month. If a go and add a user which was born the 1st of January 2005, there it doesn't let me because of the year born.